# single dimensional array battleship code

Tags: java

I am beginner in java. I was trying to emulate the single dimension array battle ship code from heads first java book. The code is not failing, but I am not able to make it work properly.

Example: `[1,2,3]` is the array which contains the location of the battle ship. If I guess any number except 1, it is displaying as miss. But if I guess it as 1 three times (length of battleship) in a row I am making it as kill. I am not able to figure out this issue.

Could you please help me out here. The code is posted below:

```
package battleship;

public class battleship {
    public int[] battleship = new int[3];
    public int numofhits = 0;
    String result = "miss";//instance variables complete

    //setter method to initialize the array which holds the battle ship location
    public void setbattleshiploc(int startpos) {
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < battleship.length; i++) {
            battleship[i] = startpos + i;
            System.out.println(battleship[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("initialized array is: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(battleship));
    }

    //getter method to print the set battleship array
    public  int[] getbattleshiploc() {
        System.out.println("Battleship array is: " + battleship);
        return battleship;
    }

    //checking whether user guess inside the battleship array location
    public String guessloc(int guessnum) {
        //int i = 0;
        for(int cell : battleship) {
            System.out.println("Guessed number is: " + guessnum + " array element: " + battleship[cell]);
            System.out.println("cell: "+ cell + " ,battleship[cell]: " + battleship[cell] );

            if(cell == guessnum) {
                numofhits++;                
                if(numofhits == 3) {
                    result = "kill";
                    return result;
                }//if the hits are 3 then return kill indicating that no more battle ship is available
                else {
                    result = "hit";
                    return result;
                }//end inner else               
            }//end outer if

            else {
                //numofhits++;
                result = "miss";
                return result;
            }//end the if-else

        }//end for loop

        return "finished";
    }//end function guessloc

}//end class



package battleship;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class gamelauncher {
public Scanner[] reader;    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "miss";
        int numofguess = 0;
        //int loopnum = 0;
        battleship launchgame = new battleship();//launch the game
        int startpos = (int) (Math.random() * 5);//generate random number between 0-4
        //int[] location = {startpos, startpos + 1, startpos + 2};//initialize three consecutive array element 
        launchgame.setbattleshiploc(startpos);//set the array as the battleship location using setter

        //display the battleship position
        System.out.println("Battle shipt positions are: " +  startpos +" ," + startpos+1 + " ," + startpos+2);
        System.out.println("the battle ship array is: " + launchgame.getbattleshiploc());
        //int[] battleshiplocation = launchgame.getbattleshiploc();
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(launchgame.getbattleshiploc()));

        while(result != "kill") {

            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            int guess = reader.nextInt(); //get the user input integer
            //reader.close();//close the scanner
            //loopnum++;

            numofguess++;
            if(guess < 0 || guess > 7) {
                System.out.println("Maximum space available is 7 units(0-6) and battleship length is 3 units, Please provide the location accordingly");
                continue;
            }//close if loop and go to the loop execution if the guess is not within the limits
            else {
                result = launchgame.guessloc(guess);
                System.out.println("response from guessing method: " + result);
                //get the status(hit/miss/kill) back from guess location method

                if(result == "kill") {
                    System.out.println("We have destroyed all the parts of battle ship and it took " + numofguess +" guesses"  );
                    break;//get out of the loop as we have destroyed everything
                }//end kill
                else if(result == "hit") {
                    System.out.println("You have destroyed " + launchgame.numofhits+" parts of batlleship, please continue");
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("It's a miss dumbo, try again");
                    continue;
                }
            }//end outer else statement
        }//end while loop

    }//end main method

}//end class
```

Comment: You shouldn't return "miss" immediately when a part is missed, you should return it only if ALL the parts are missed.

Comment: If the goal of that example was to show how to handle arrays I would throw that book into the garbage. Not joking here. Anyway don´t compare Strings with numeric operators like !=, == and so on. Instead use string1.equals(string2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you by giving you this function a bit changed. Please try to fix the rest of your code on your own. It will give you important experience.

```
public String guessloc(int guessnum) {
    for(int i=0;i<battleship.length;++i) {
        if(battleship[i] == guessnum) { //it's a hit
            battleship[i] = -1; //you cant hit it again, so change it
            if(++numofhits == 3) {
                return "kill";
            }else
                return "hit";
            }
    }
    return "miss"; //miss should be outside of the for loop
}
```

Comment: I used the function provided and did the below changes

Comment: I used the function provided and did the below changes. 1) used .equals for string comparision as said above 2) changed the function a bit as numofhits++; if(numofhits == battleship[i]). Thanks for the suggestions, code worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that when you are comparing Strings u are using == instead of .equals() so your code should like like this:

```
if(result.equals("kill"))
```

Comment: *Improvement* do `"kill".equals(result)` because `null.equals("string") => NullPointerException` while `"string".equals(null) => false` :)

Comment: In general, this is true. But in their implementation it's fine. They're assigning the literals `"kill"`/`"hit"` in all cases. Those will all be references to the same object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't know that thank you for sharing.